# Portknoking: слежение за upd сокетами

Tags: c, сокет, ubuntu

Пытаюсь реализовать систему portknoking на upd сокетах. Залип на том, чтобы ожидать по таймеру подключение ко второму и 3 сокетам. Т.е. чтобы подключение только по одному порту не ломало систему. Что подскажите? И как предложите код оптимизировать?

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char**argv)

{
int sock1,sock2,sock3,namelen;
    struct sockaddr_in addr1,addr2,addr3,reserv_addr;
    char buf[1024];
    char test[]={"1\n"};
    int bytes_read;

    sock1 = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    sock2 = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    sock3 = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if((sock1 < 0)||(sock2 < 0)||(sock3<0))
    {
        perror("socket");
        exit(1);
    }
    addr1.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr1.sin_port = htons(31546);
    addr2.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr2.sin_port = htons(31644);
    addr3.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr3.sin_port = htons(31544);
    addr1.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

    if(bind(sock1, (struct sockaddr *)&addr1, sizeof(addr1)) < 0)
    {
        perror("bind");
        exit(1);
    }

    while(1)
    {
        bytes_read = recvfrom(sock1, buf, 1024, 0, &reserv_addr, &namelen);
        buf[bytes_read] = '\0';
        printf(buf);
        if (buf!=0)//(strncmp(buf,test,3)==0)
        {
            addr2.sin_addr.s_addr = addr1.sin_addr.s_addr;

            break;
        }
    }
        if(bind(sock1, (struct sockaddr *)&addr1, sizeof(addr1)) < 0)
    {
        perror("bind");
        exit(1);
    }
    while(1)
    {
        bytes_read = recvfrom(sock1, buf, 1024, 0, &reserv_addr, &namelen);
        buf[bytes_read] = '\0';
        printf(buf);
        if (buf!=0)
        {
            addr3.sin_addr.s_addr = addr1.sin_addr.s_addr;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы лучше русским языком поподробней расскажите, что именно хотите сделать?

Если одновременно слушать 3 разных порта, то сделайте bind для каждого из них на сокеты и дальше используйте `poll()` (или `select()`).

**Обновление**

Прочесть [man select](http://linux.die.net/man/3/select), заполнять `fd_set readfds` значениями файловых дескрипторов сокетов, устанавливать таймаут, вызывать `select()`  в цикле и анализировать результат вызова.

Comment: @avp Но как в моем случае стоит использовать select()? bind я для всех сделал уже.

Comment: Прочесть [man select](http://linux.die.net/man/3/select), заполнять `fd_set readfds` значениями файловых дескрипторов сокетов, устанавливать таймаут, вызывать `select()`  в цикле и анализировать результат вызова.

Answer (score 1):

Portknocking реализуется, анализируя логи файервола или перехватывая трафик (pcap) на интерфейсе (таком как `eth0`). Вот [рабочий пример кода](https://github.com/jvinet/knock). Идея в том, что все порты закрыты по умолчанию. Если слушать выбранные порты (то есть эти порты уже открыты), то можно просто пароль передать.

Если хочется в качестве упражнения добавить ограничение по времени, то можно `select(2)` использовать, чтобы ограничить время ожидания следующего соединения, как [[@avp](/users/232/avp)](/users/232/avp) сказал это заодно позволить слушать на нескольких портах и поддерживать нескольких клиентов http://goo.gl/PSVKx3